# how to use drupal xmlrpc for node.create

Tags: php, drupal, xml-rpc

I am using `drupal xmlrpc` 
I won't to use `XMLRPC POST` for `node.create`
in my c# application 
but I get an `error 401 Access denied for user anonymous` 
and I did not find where I can put the user name and password for the user
am using the example [here](http://drupal.org/node/1304802) 
http://drupal.org/node/1304802

please help am new in `drupal` and `drupal` documentation actually very Missy for me

here the post **xml** code

```
   <?xml version='1.0' ?>
<methodCall>
  <methodName>node.create</methodName>
  <params>
    <param>
      <value>
        <struct>
          <member>
            <name>type</name>
            <value>
              <string>story</string>
            </value>
          </member>
          <member>
            <name>body</name>
            <value>
              <string>Create body input</string>
            </value>
          </member>
          <member>
            <name>title</name>
            <value>
              <string>Test title</string>
            </value>
          </member>
        </struct>
      </value>
    </param>
  </params>
</methodCall>
```

Answer (score 0):

first login into drupal site by admin.then try to do this.i think it will work..

Answer (score 0):

I know it is very late for responding to your question.
First of all, the XML example you posted is for use with Drupal 6. If you are using Drupal 7, then node.create ressource will be like below example:

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<methodCall>
  <methodName>node.create</methodName>
  <params>
    <param>
      <value>
        <struct>
          <member>
            <name>type</name>
            <value>
              <string>article</string>
            </value>
          </member>
          <member>
            <name>body</name>
            <value>
              <struct>
                <member>
                  <name>und</name>
                  <value>
                    <array>
                      <data>
                        <value>
                          <struct>
                            <member>
                              <name>value</name>
                              <value>
                                <string>My test body text.</string>
                              </value>
                            </member>
                          </struct>
                        </value>
                      </data>
                    </array>
                  </value>
                </member>
              </struct>
            </value>
          </member>
          <member>
            <name>title</name>
            <value>
              <string>My test node title</string>
            </value>
          </member>
        </struct>
      </value>
    </param>
  </params>
</methodCall>
```

Depending on how you set your services persmissions, your should be authentified user or not. You can just disable " Session authentication " in http:/your_domain/admin/structure/services/list/your_endpoint/edit for testing.
If your still need help, please feel free to ask any question.